# MergeError: Can not pass on, right_on, left_on or set right_index=True or left_index=True

Tags: pandas

While using `cross` merge in pandas I am getting the following error. The error message makes little sense to me and I have tried to search on the internet but this error is not mentioned anywhere:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,1,2,2,3],'b':[10,11,12,13,14,15]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,2,2,2,4,4],'a':[15,16,17,18,19,20,21]})

pd.merge(df1,df2,on='id',how='cross')

output:
MergeError: Can not pass on, right_on, left_on or set right_index=True or left_index=True
```

Every other merge strategy works except for `cross`

Can you please help me understand why am I getting this error and what it means?

Comment: You can't specify an `on` for `cross`. It doesn't make sense. `cross` gives you the Cartesian product of all rows in both frames. Since it gives all rows from both frames there is no way to anchor this around a particular column or index.

Comment: Check the last example of the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

Answer (score 3):

According to the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge.html):
`"When performing a cross merge, no column specifications to merge on are allowed".`
This is because all columns are involved, so there is no need to specify a column:

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, how='cross')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write like this:

```
df1.merge(df2, how='cross')
```